# There is a re-direct issue with nginx when deploying asp.net core application on ubuntu server

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, nginx

I have facing issue with nginx server when deploying asp.net core application actually it always redirect it to localhost but I pass the proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000 on nginx config file.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you should try this

```
location / {
      # http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver
      resolver 127.0.0.1 valid=30s ipv6=off;
      # http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver_timeout
      # give up and response error 
      resolver_timeout 5s;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000; 
}
```

Comment: Yeah I try this but this also not working, don't know what is the problem with my nginx config. still getting **This site can’t be reached**.